# @OneToMany JPA Relationships toward the same Class

Tags: jpa, one-to-many, entity-relationship, many-to-one

I'm building a simple Spring Application, I need help finding the right design for some JPA Entities, here is the case that I have :

- One `FirstResource` Has many Actions
- One `SecondResource` Has many Actions
- One `ThirdResource` Has many Actions

> My goal : I want to be able to add actions to a specific
>   resource, or list all the actions done on a resource for example.

The 4 Entities are (FirstResource, SecondResource, ThirdResource, Action), Should they be like this ? :

```
@Entity
public class Action implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idAction;
    private String nameAction; // + gettes & setters...
}

@Entity
public class FirstResource implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idFirstResource;
    private int unitNumber; // + gettes & setters...
}

@Entity
public class SecondResource implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idSecondResource;
    private String nameSecondResource; // + gettes & setters...
}

@Entity
public class ThirdResource implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idThirdResource;
    private boolean Confirmed; // + gettes & setters...
}
```

So should the class `Action` have references annotated with `@ManyToOne` to each of the `Resources` ? If yes, Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use inheritance.

Define an abstract class AbstractResource as an Entity :

```
@Entity
public abstract class AbstractResource implements Serializable {
  @Id @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  @OneToMany
  private List<Action> actions;
...
}
```

Then make sure your resources class extend AbstractResource :

```
@Entity
public class FirstResource extends AbstractResource
```

And then you can reference your resources inside your Action entity :

```
@Entity
public class Action implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idAction;

    @ManyToOne
    private AbstractResource resource;
 ...
}
```

As you cannot use MappedSuperClass with ManyToOne relations, you cannot use @MappedSuperClass in your case.

Comment: I understand, that's what I'm going to do. Thank you.